# PHP Zend Engine Extension static method call

Tags: php, c, php-extension, php-internals

I am writing a PHP extension. From the C code I try to invoke a static method in PHP code.

The PHP-method looks like this:

```
<?php
class Model {
  static method GetModelById($id) { ... }
}
?>
```

The call in C looks like this:

```
if( call_user_function_ex(
      &((*ce)->function_table),
      NULL, &fname, &retval_ptr,
      1, func_params, 0, NULL TSRMLS_CC
    ) == SUCCESS
){
  // do some stuff here ...
}
```

... where all passed parameters should contain proper values. The strange thing here is: if I compile my extension against php 5.2 the code works fine, if I compile this against php 5.3, the method call fails with no error message.

I also tried `zend_call_method` with no success in either version.

Can anyone give a tip for me? How would you call a static method from C?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Sorry guys, I got it working via `zend_call_method` like so:

```
if( zend_call_method( NULL, *ce, NULL, 
                     "getmodelbyid", 
                     strlen("getmodelbyid"), 
                     &retval_ptr, 1, p1, 
                     NULL TSRMLS_CC ) == FAILURE) {
    php_printf("gosh!");
} 
else {
    php_printf("yep!"); 
}
```

... so I learned:

1. Function names must always be in lowercase
2. You better have a look at PHP's source code when it comes to string lengths (`zend_call_method` adds +1 internally).

Although I am new to C, I think the PHP code base is over-compilcated in many ways!

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Peter, would you mind pasting this into the answer section, submitting and then marking the answer as accepted to indicate the question has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, it helps those of us digging through unanswered questions to know it's already been resolved.